# Google App Engine - Run job based on user input time

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have an app running on GAE cloud (Java web application). I have gone through the documentation that shows how to create the cron jobs (using cron.xml that we place in WEB-INF). However the frequency is also set in the same config file along with time/date.

If I need to run a job (or more than one job) based on the User input how do I achieve that? For example, if there is a text box on the web app jsp that allows the User to input 11:30 am, how do I run a specific job at that time? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave an answer to a similar question [here - Best way to schedule code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27533693/4316235).  Basically have a cron job run at a certain frequency to check datastore to see if there is anything to run at that time.  You can restrict user input to 15 minute increments and have the cron job check every 15 minutes or at whatever rate you need.